# Policy doesn't work on route middleware in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 which allows user to Post contents. On My app, I have different roles:
`admin - can do all`
`editor - can update/delete his own post` 
`client - cannot update/delete any post`

Role Model

```
class Role extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;

 const ADMIN_ROLE   = 1;
 const EDITOR_ROLE  = 2;
 const CLIENT_ROLE  = 3;
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function role()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
  }
}
```

I created a policy which will restrict the auth user from updating/deleting a post.

```
class PostPolicy
{
  use HandlesAuthorization;

 /**
  * Only owner or admin can excecute the operation.
  */
  public function doCommonAction(User $user, Post $post)
  {
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }

    // make sure that the post belongs to the auth user wherein $post->created_by is the user id 
    return $user->id == $post->created_by; 
  }

  public function update(User $user, Post $post)
  {
    return $this->doCommonAction($user, $post);
  }

  public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
  {
    return $this->doCommonAction($user, $post);
  }
}
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::delete('/user-posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])
         ->middleware('can:delete,post')
         ->name('delete');  // I need to use /user-posts endpoint here.
```

**Error Message:** "This action is unauthorized.",

I tried to change the middleware to
`->middleware('can:delete,App\Models\Post')`

**Error Message:** Too few arguments to function App\Policies\PostPolicy::delete(), 1 passed in Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 799 and exactly 2 expected.

Even if I return delete() Policy to `true`, still the same error.

Is there any way to fix this on middleware route?

Comment: probably because ``PostPolicy`` can't be injected because of non ``type hint`` parameter for the route. You should change ``{{id}}`` to ``{post}}`` to make ``PostPolicy`` injection successful.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I added this method in controller and it worked.
`public function destroy(){
  $this->authorize('delete', Post::find($id));
}`

But, I need it to run on route api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved.

First, I changed the route parameter:

```
Route::delete('/user-posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])
     ->middleware('can:delete,post'); // from {id} to {post}
```

Next, I to accept the Post type in my method.

```
class PostController{
  public function destroy(Post $post) { // Need to pass the argument as Post type
     //
  }
}
```