# Passing multiple arguments to the Laravel Policy correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a simple API using Laravel just to know the framework better and trying to figure out how can I pass arguments to my Policy correctly. I have a CarController with `update()` method inside it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Contracts\CarRepositoryContract;
use App\Events\CarDestroyedEvent;
use App\Events\CarStoredEvent;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Car\StoreCarRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Car\UpdateCarRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\Car\CarResource;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    public $repository;

    public function __construct(CarRepositoryContract $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    // ...

    public function update(UpdateCarRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $result = $this->repository->update($validated, $id);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $result,
        ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've created a CarPolicy and added my `update()` method logic:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class CarPolicy
{    

    // ...

    public function update(User $user, Car $car): bool
    {
        return $user->roles()->pluck('name')->first() == 'Admin'
            || ($user->roles()->pluck('name')->first() == 'Visitor' && $user->id == $car->user_id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In my api.php I'm adding a `middleware()` to my route to protect it

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {

    // ...
    
    Route::put('/cars/{id}', [CarController::class, 'update'])->middleware('can:update,App\Model\Car');

    // ...
});
```

I've also connected my Policty in the `AuthServiceProvider.php` file like this:

```
protected $policies = [
        Car::class => CarPolicy::class,
    ];
```

But it does not do anything at all. If I try to add multiple parameters to the `middleware()` method in different ways in the `api.php` I get an error message that:

1. I'm passing a few arguments (If I add only `App\Model\Car`)
2. The second argument is a type of string (If I try to add `App\Model\User` and `App\Model\Car`)
3. The second argument is a type of null (If I try to add `App\Model\Car` and something else)

My problem is I can't really understand how and what data should be passed correctly. I appreciate any help and sorry if my question looks stupid. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out thanks to the guys from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148335/policy-doesnt-work-on-route-middleware-in-laravel-8?rq=2)

Comment: You can post your answer below, so it will be useful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, you need to pass a `Class` in your URL like this:

```
Route::get('/cars/{car}', [CarController::class, 'show'])->middleware('can:view,car');
    Route::put('/cars/{car}', [CarController::class, 'update'])->middleware('can:update,car');
    Route::delete('/cars/{car}', [CarController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('can:delete,car');
```

and the use it inside your controller:

```
public function destroy(Car $car)
    {
        $result = $this->repository->destroy($car->id);

        event(new CarDestroyedEvent(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name));

//        MailSendJob::dispatch(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $result,
        ]);
    }
```

Again many thanks to those guys from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148335/policy-doesnt-work-on-route-middleware-in-laravel-8?rq=2)